# HTML- prepend all links

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML template that I'd like to paste onto a google site (embedded code). It has a table of 500+ links. 
I would like to prepend all of these links. Is there a way I can do this without using JS?

```html
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" id="votingmembers">
<thead><tr style="vertical-align:bottom;">
<th class="headerSort headerSortUp" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort descending">District</th>
<th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Representative</th>
<th colspan="2" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Party</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>

<style>

.vcard{
display:none;
}

body{
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
color: black;
}


</style>



<tr>
<td><a href="/wiki/Alabama%27s_1st_congressional_district" title="Alabama's 1st congressional district">Alabama 1</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/wiki/File:Rep_Bradley_Byrne_(cropped).jpg" class="image"><img alt="Rep Bradley Byrne (cropped).jpg" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Rep_Bradley_Byrne_%28cropped%29.jpg/75px-Rep_Bradley_Byrne_%28cropped%29.jpg" width="75" height="103" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Rep_Bradley_Byrne_%28cropped%29.jpg/113px-Rep_Bradley_Byrne_%28cropped%29.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Rep_Bradley_Byrne_%28cropped%29.jpg/150px-Rep_Bradley_Byrne_%28cropped%29.jpg 2x" data-file-width="1700" data-file-height="2337"></a> <span class="sortkey">Byrne, Bradley</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Bradley_Byrne" title="Bradley Byrne">Bradley Byrne</a></span></span></td>
<td style="background-color:#E81B23"></td>
<td>Republican</td>
<br>
</tr><tr>

<td><a href="/wiki/Alabama%27s_2nd_congressional_district" title="Alabama's 2nd congressional district">Alabama 2</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/wiki/File:Martha_roby_113_congressional_portrait_(cropped).jpg" class="image"><img alt="Martha roby 113 congressional portrait (cropped).jpg" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Martha_roby_113_congressional_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/75px-Martha_roby_113_congressional_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg" width="75" height="108" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Martha_roby_113_congressional_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/113px-Martha_roby_113_congressional_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Martha_roby_113_congressional_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg/150px-Martha_roby_113_congressional_portrait_%28cropped%29.jpg 2x" data-file-width="994" data-file-height="1430"></a> <span class="sortkey">Roby, Martha</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Martha_Roby" title="Martha Roby">Martha Roby</a></span></span></td>
<td style="background-color:#E81B23"></td>
<td>Republican</td>
```

Comment: Prepend them with what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

```
<style>
    a:before {
        content: "Your prepend content ";
    }
</style>
```

Or use a simple search/replace of the HTML in a text editor.